# How to get an attribute value of a web element which is hidden?

Tags: python, selenium

I am struggling to get the attribute value of a web element which is actually hidden on the page. I am using python+selenium and I do not nkow how to get this value. Please help!
For your reference, here is a sample python code that I have written:

```
AttValueBeforeUpdateButtonAppears = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(lambda     driver:self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(CustomizeYourCheck.UPDATE_BUTTON_HIDDEN).get_attribute('style'))

print AttValueBeforeUpdateButtonAppears
self.assertIn("hidden", AttValueBeforeUpdateButtonAppears)
```

Comment: This is the css locator that I have written for CustomizeYourCheck.UPDATE_BUTTON_HIDDEN-> 'span[id='UpdatePrice2'][style='visibility:hidden;']' and it locates correctly when I do it in FirePath

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15049248/771848

Comment: @alecxe:This is what I wrote. I dont get the hidden button(actually an image) so that I can take it's style attribute value. `try: abc = self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('UpdatePrice2').style.display='block'")
print abc
AttValueBeforeUpdateButtonAppears = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(CustomizeYourCheck.UPDATE_BUTTON_HIDDEN).get_attribute('style')
print AttValueBeforeUpdateButtonAppears         self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('UpdatePrice2').style.display='none'")
except NoSuchElementException:
assert 0, "Can't find hidden button"`

Comment: @Praveen When you have extra information, it's better to edit your question to include it there. If you put it in a comment it's much harder to read, and it's more difficult for any new reader to understand the question without scanning through all the comments.