# How to access hidden file upload field with Selenium WebDriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have such HTML:

```
<a id="buttonToUpload" class="btn-pink medium" href="#">
    <span class="icon-arrow-right">upload photo</span>
</a>
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" style="visibility: hidden">
</form>
```

Pressing on  raise system dialog for choosing file, which I can't access via webdriver.
I tried send_keys() directly to  but it raises ElementNotVisibleException. So how can I upload photo there?
Actual code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www........')
upload_input = driver.find_element_by_id('uploadImage')
upload_input.send_keys(os.getcwd()+'/image.jpg')
```

Comment: please show exact code you used to upload image

Comment: Please try to apply solution proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049182/write-value-to-hidden-element-with-selenium-python-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved with this:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('uploadImage'‌​).style.visibility='‌​visible'")
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute JavaScript to make the input element visible before interacting with it.

```
driver.execute_script("""document.querySelector("div.yourClassNameHere input[type=file]").style.display='block'""")

# Send the absolute file path of the file to the input element
input = browser.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@type='file']")
input.sendKeys(os.path.abspath("image.jpg"))
```

Make sure you replace the queries with ones that make sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

I myself ran into this problem where my 'input' element looked like while using Cucumber tests with Selenium:

```
<input type="file" autocomplete="off" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
```

This is how I solved it:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =(JavascriptExecutor) StepDef.driver;
        jse.executeScript("document.querySelector('" + elementSelector +"').style.display='block';");

        util.elementXpathIsVisible(elementXpath);
        StepDef.driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementXpath)).sendKeys(filePath);
```