# Importing image to google forms via selenium driver in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to import image to the google form. I am failing to pass keys to the element via xpath. It seems it is a hidden element.

I have tried to execute scripts to unhide it, but with no success. 
Tried this solutions also:
[How to access hidden file upload field with Selenium WebDriver python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844294/how-to-access-hidden-file-upload-field-with-selenium-webdriver-python)

[Python-Selenium "input type file" upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49275041/python-selenium-input-type-file-upload)

Does anybody have a method to import to google forms via drag and drop file dialog box.

I usually get an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

I am sending some pseudocode:

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()




browser.get('ANY GOOGLE FORM URL')


browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[3]/span/span').click()


fileinput = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Nf-Er-Xr')]")
fileinput.send_keys('some image path')
```

Comment: Try adding a time.sleep() after browser.get()  - sometimes the webpages take a long time to load.

Comment: Tried that, it is not a problem. The problem is in a fileinput part. It just cant find the element, by xpath or id. It is somehow hidden, and i quess i need to execute some kind of script to unhide it. But i am stuck on that, nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On clicking the *ADD FILE* button in Google Forms, it opens up a pop-up, which is an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). An `iframe` is basically an HTML page embedded into another one. In order to anything with it, you have to tell Selenium to switch the context to that `iframe`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python) SO question which explains how you'd go about switching context to an `iframe`. For your specific case, i.e. Google Forms, the code would be ―

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_class_name('picker-frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
input_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
```

Comment: This works beautifully. I didnt know i need to approach it as a new frame. Thank you very much SkullTech!