# Google Forms Image Upload with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

how to use selenium to upload an image in google form? i was already searching and nothing comes up, iam also already tried to find the upload button with xpath and this comes up

````
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div"}```
````

Comment: Take a look at this feed, the topic has already been discussed. Maybe this might be your solution, too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56595699/importing-image-to-google-forms-via-selenium-driver-in-python

Comment: @SvenEschlbeck thanks a lot brother